# Flutter gridview - list of traversed containers

Tags: flutter, gesturedetector

I have a Gridview with count 25 and containers in it. I need to identify list of containers those are passed through swipe action by user.

Codes snippet:

```
   GestureDetector(
    onPanUpdate:(details) {
     setState((){
     // Logic here
                      });
                    },
                    child: Container( key: gKey,)
```

This list of selected containers will be used to show changed color.

I tried a Gesture Detector and Listener but had no success.  I can get offset from pan details but don't know how to identify the widget from it.

Answer (score 0):

*I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but it seems like you have a `GridView` and want to change the color for each child, your just aren't aware on how to get which child was selected*

Instead of using GridView, you can use [`GridView.builder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridView/GridView.builder.html), which has an `itemBuilder` which has and `index` for each item.

Here's an example that I created. First, create a StateFul widget with:

```dart
  final _colors = List<Color>.filled(25, Colors.grey);
  final _data = List<String>.generate(25, (i) => "Item $i");
```

then, create a GridView.builder with the itemBuilder as:

```dart
 itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  // if the color is grey, change it to blue, else change it to grey
                  _colors[index] =
                      _colors[index] == Colors.grey ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey;
                });
              },
              child: Container(
                color: _colors[index],
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    _data[index],
                    style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          })
```

the code is self-explanatory: it will change the color from grey to blue when tapped on.

---

Here is the complete runnable snippet:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter gridview demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final _colors = List<Color>.filled(25, Colors.grey);
  final _data = List<String>.generate(25, (i) => "Item $i");

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GridView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 5,
            mainAxisSpacing: 10,
            crossAxisSpacing: 10,
          ),
          itemCount: _data.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  // if the color is grey, change it to blue, else change it to grey
                  _colors[index] =
                      _colors[index] == Colors.grey ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey;
                });
              },
              child: Container(
                color: _colors[index], // Use color from _colors list
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    _data[index],
                    style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  Could you please help me with swipe action? your example is working for tap action. But if user swipes over multiple containers then those containers should change the color while swiping.